# Need help reversing this function

Tags: javascript, math

I have a function that I need to get the input given the output;

```
let w = [1/16,1/9];
function warp(x,y){
    return [( x*2-1 ) * (1.0 + Math.pow( y*2-1, 2 ) * w[0]) * 0.5 + 0.5,
            ( y*2-1 ) * (1.0 + Math.pow( x*2-1, 2 ) * w[1]) * 0.5 + 0.5];
}
```

x and y are always between 0.0 and 1.0

I've tried doing this myself, but the half remembered math classes of yesteryear just result in me getting something that simplifies to 0=0

The warp function above is used in a shader to create a CRT like distortion.
And I want to take the position of a mouse on the screen, and work out where on the CRT's original render location it is.
Unfortunately my math skills are not up to the same scratch that my js skills are.

Comment: what's the value of x and y?

Comment: Any value between the range of 0.0 and 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to reverse this function. Moreover, this is function of two variables, and you cannot get unique solution for both variables.

Note that this function looks monotone and its isolines form ellipses, function resembles elliptic paraboloid

[image]

So you can:

- fix one variable (i.e. y = 0), or x/y ratio
- use some numerical [root-finding method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) to retrieve a particular solution